# Why do some IDC connectors have gaps?

Tags: connector, header

At my work we use IDC headers and cable terminators a fair bit, and we've noticed that most headers have a gap on the sides (see image below). It looks like a clip would grab the gap nicely, but have never seen any cable terminators with any such thing. My question is why might the gap be there?

[image: 2×5-pin IDC header (box-shape shroud? with pins poking up internally) showing two rectangular gaps on the side]

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist no, you're looking at the wrong gap. OP said the gaps on the sides, which *are* for retention clips, as Ignacio pointed out in his answer. Read the whole question otherwise you could have caused more confusion!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're for retainer clips, but almost no one ever uses them these days. If additional retention is required then special headers with clips on the side are used instead.

[page 5](https://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/485877O/3m-four-wall-header-d2500-series-ts-2244.pdf)

[image: 50-pin IDC retaining clip]